# get input value from user

Tags: flutter, dart, user-input, dart-null-safety

I was using an online compiler where I write simple code for the grading system but it cannot input from users about marks. I tried many youtube tutorials and articles to fix this nothing is working

```
print("Enter Your Marks");
String marks = stdin.readLineSync(); 
print("You Enter ${marks} marks");
```

[image: input function not working]

help me to solve this issue in this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this

```
String? marks = stdin.readLineSync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view this reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dart-standard-input-output/

```
import 'dart:io';
print("Enter Your Marks");
String? marks = stdin.readLineSync();
print("You Enter ${marks} marks");
```

Answer (score 0):

`readLineSync` returns nullable String. Therefore, you cannot  assign it on `String`.

In order to accept nullable data dart use `dataType? yourVariableName`

For your case,

```dart
  String? marks = stdin.readLineSync();
```

You can explore more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: still facing the same error...your tip not working